# Challenge: Prove $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}=e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}\ \ \mathrm{erf}(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, recreational-mathematics

I stumbled upon this cute sum while messing about, and I want to see what other solutions people propose before I put forward my own (which may be unnecessarily complicated).

You can use any maths you like.

NB: $\displaystyle \mathrm{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$

Comment: Maybe other people don't find it as cute as I do :(. Remember, this is just for fun

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Depending on how you define $\rm erf$, things can change a lot...$e^{1/4}$ and $\rm erf(1/2)$ can both be defined by infinite series, so a Cauchy product should give the answer. (Didn't downvote, but am considering -- as it stands, without the definitions one should start with, the question is very open to interpretation).

Comment: Maybe I should have asked this question on a Sunday!!

Comment: People here don't like to be challenged. They want to show they are smart, not that the OP is smart. You shouldn't say that you know the solution. By the way I am interested in the solution +1.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ZaidAlyafeai if I have another question like this at some point I will phrase it differently.

Comment: Perhaps this question should belong to the [Puzzling SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I find it interesting how much this split the community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall for all $x > 0$,
$$\sinh x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{\sinh \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}
$$
and the integral representation of $n!$
$$n! = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}dx$$

The sum at hand can be rewritten as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{(2n+1)!}  e^{-x}dx
= \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}\right)dx
= \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac{\sinh\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx
$$
Change variable to $t = \sqrt{x}$, this reduces to
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}(e^t - e^{-t}) dt
= e^{\frac14}\int_0^\infty \left(e^{-(t-\frac12)^2} - e^{-(t+\frac12)^2}\right)dt
= e^{\frac14}\left(\int_{-\frac12}^\infty - \int_{\frac12}^\infty\right) e^{-t^2}dt\\
= e^{\frac14}\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} e^{-t^2}dt
= 2e^{\frac14}\int_0^{\frac12} e^{-t^2}dt
= e^{\frac14}\sqrt{\pi}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac12\right)
$$

Comment: This is, at heart, very similar to my answer below, but cooler

Answer (score 3):

Simply, by using Euler's beta function,
$$S=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B(n+1,n+1)}{n!}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n!}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}e^{x(1-x)}\,dx$$
and by setting $x=t+\frac{1}{2}$
$$ S = \int_{0}^{1}e^{x(1-x)}\,dx = 2e^{1/4} \int_{0}^{1/2}e^{-t^2}\,dt.$$

Comment: Shortest possible answer. +1

Comment: For the the downvoter: Explain. Your. Downvote.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:**

- We know that $$e^{1/4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n} n!}$$
- and that $$\begin{align}
  \sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &= \int_0^{1/2} e^{-t^2}dt 
  = \int_0^{1/2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{n!} dt
  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^{1/2} t^{2n} dt
  \\
  &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n! 2^{2n}} \frac{1}{2n+1}
  \end{align}$$

so that, writing it as a product of series and using the Cauchy product of these,
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) e^{1/4} 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n! 2^{2n}} \frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n} n!}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k! 2^{2k} (2k+1)}\frac{1}{(n-k)!2^{2n-2k}} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (2k+1)}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}n!}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
\end{align}$$
and from there it is not hard to conclude from the properties of the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Complex_arguments).

*(If needed, I can fill in the remaining steps later.)*

---

**Finishing it:**
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
= \frac{2^n n!}{(2n+1)!!}
= \frac{2^n n!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{n+1}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n+1)}
\end{align}$$
from which, using the [properties of the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General),
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!!}{2^{2n}n!(2n+1)!!}
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n+1}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n+1)}
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}2^{2n+2}(n+1)!}{2^{2n+1}\sqrt{\pi}(2n+2)!}\\
&= \frac{2 (n+1)n!}{2(n+1)(2n+1)!}
= \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align}$$
and we are done.

Comment: Nice effort! Just not sure it's as elegant as the other answer, plus it's working back from the result

Comment: @shakespeare If you don't like to flow of the development, simply work from the bottom to the top.

Comment: @Shakespeare Elegance is nice, but I never claimed it. (Also, with regard to "working backwards" — the very premise of this question is that we are *given the answer* and want to prove it.

Comment: What you both say is true about working backwards. But even reading bottom up, this answer is very inspired by the result; obviously Achille Hui's is too, but it feels like just summing the series as opposed to figuring out how to derive the series from the result. It's not a bad thing, just a matter of personal taste

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle I_n= \int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-x^2}dx$.

Let $S=\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{I_n}{n!}=\int_0^{\infty}e^xe^{-x^2}dx=e^{1/4}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(x-1/2)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}(\mathrm{erf}(\frac{1}{2})+1)$.

Splitting $S$ into odd and even parts, have

$\displaystyle S_{\mathrm{even}}=\sum_{n \geq 0} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2n!}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} (e^{x}+e^{-x})e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}$

So $\displaystyle S_{\mathrm{odd}}=\frac{1}{2} e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}\ \ \mathrm{erf}(\frac{1}{2})$.

Conclude using $\displaystyle I_{2n+1}=\frac{n!}{2}$ (from integration by parts).

We get $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}=e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}\ \ \mathrm{erf}(\frac{1}{2})$.